# How to write a matcher that is not equal to something

Tags: java, junit, mockito, matcher

I am trying to create a mock for a call.
Say I have this method I am trying to stub out:

```
class ClassA {
  public String getString(String a) {
    return a + "hey";
  }
}
```

What I am trying to mock out is:
1st instance is

```
when(classA.getString(eq("a")).thenReturn(...);`
```

in the same test case

```
when(classA.getString([anything that is not a])).thenReturn(somethingelse);
```

The 2nd case is my question: How do I match `anyString()` other than "a"?

Comment: I think you could mark the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 137, accepted):

With `Mockito` framework, you can use [AdditionalMatchers](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.23.0/org/mockito/AdditionalMatchers.html)

```
ClassA classA = Mockito.mock(ClassA.class);
Mockito.when(classA.getString(Matchers.eq("a"))).thenReturn("something"); 
Mockito.when(classA.getString(AdditionalMatchers.not(Matchers.eq("a")))).thenReturn("something else");
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: AdditionalMatchers seems to removed by now.

Comment: Hi @PieterDeBie I think AdditionalMatchers is still in the current Mockito version. [See it on the github project](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/blob/release/2.x/src/main/java/org/mockito/AdditionalMatchers.java)

Comment: As Matchers is deprecated, use ArgumentMatchers instead. See also here: https://zgrepcode.com/mockito/2.24.8/org/mockito/matchers.java

Comment: There is a notable caveat here though. The return type of AdditionalMatchers::not is 0 for all numeric primitives, false for the boolean primitive and *null* for all non primitive objects T. This means that you will run into ugly warnings when you try to use it on mocked methods where the parameters are annotated with @Nonnull.

Answer (score 10):

Use `argThat` with Hamcrest:

```
when(classA.getString(argThat(CoreMatchers.not(CoreMatchers.equalTo("a")))...
```

You might also be able to do this via ordering. If you put one `when(anyString)` and `when(eq("a"))` in the correct order, Mockito should test them in order and do the "a" logic when appropriate and then "anyString" logic otherwise.

Answer (score 10):

In mockito the last stubbing is the most important. This means that you can simply use the standard matchers for your needs:

```
// "Default" return values.
when(classA.getString(ArgumentMatchers.anyString())).thenReturn(somethingelse);
// Specific return value for "a"
when(classA.getString(ArgumentMatchers.eq("a"))).thenReturn(something);
```

Note that you **have** to use ArgumentMatchers for both since you're mixing them.

Answer (score 1):

I actually took this approach after carefully looking at the suggested answers:

```
doAnswer(new Answer<String>() {
  public String answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
    String originalParam = (String) invocation.getArguments()[0];
    return StringUtils.equalsIgnoreCase(originalParam, "a") ? "Something" : "Something Else";
  }
}).when(classA).getString(anyString());
```

This allows me to handle more than just two cases by adjusting the return base on the params.

Comment: This is a good solution but I think both mine and @John B anwers are closer to your OP requeriments.