# Mockito: Match any String except one

Tags: java, string, junit, mockito, matcher

How can I write a matcher using Mockito that matches any string except a specific one?

I have tried using some hamcrest matchers to negate and combine other matchers, but the hamcrest matchers all return values of type `Matcher<T>` which dont work very well with Mockito matchers.

Comment: Use `argThat(yourHamcrestMatcher)`. http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/Matchers.html

Comment: @JBNizet i assume that works because `argThat(matcher())` essentially converts the return type from `Matcher<T>` to `<T>`?

Comment: @JNNizet: the url of the docs is now http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/Matchers.html

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The solution I used:

```
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.not;
import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.argThat;

// ...

argThat(not("ExceptionString"))
```

**Versions**

- [Mockito 3.3.3](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.3.3)
- [Hamcrest 1.3](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hamcrest/hamcrest-core/1.3)

Answer (score 25):

Just point that with `Mockito` you can also use [AdditionalMatchers](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/AdditionalMatchers.html) and [ArgumentMatchers](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/ArgumentMatchers.html)

```
import static org.mockito.AdditionalMatchers.not;
import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.eq;

//anything but not "ejb"    
mock.someMethod(not(eq("ejb")));
```

According its documentation:

> Example of using logical and(), not(), or() matchers:
>
> //anything but not "ejb"
>   mock.someMethod(not(eq("ejb")));

There is more info in this other [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26067096/how-to-write-a-matcher-that-is-not-equal-to-something)

Hope it helps