# How to have different return type for different parameters using Mockito?

Tags: java, mocking, mockito

I am using Mockito to define something like this -

```
when(serviceInvocation.isServiceNeeded("4105706432","AAS")).thenReturn(true);
```

Similar to "4105706432" , I have just 4 other string values which must have return value true. 
However, for any other string , I need return type to be false.

How can this be implemented?

Comment: what's the problem to make it the same way you did in your example but with other strings?

Comment: For 5 strings , it is fixed that I must have return type true. For any other, it must be false. I can't specify every other string which will be false. There may be so many strings.

Comment: Did you try this approach? https://stackoverflow.com/a/30108950/4563745

Comment: Thanx for the source. But will this approach work for 5 strings. I mean the approach mentions just 1 string. Sorry if my questions are stupid.

Answer (score 1):

Use an ArgumentCaptor the capture the param: then you can check if it's one of the correct values:

```
ArgumentCaptor<String> captor= ArgumentCaptor.forClass(String.class);
Mockito.verify(mock).doSomething(captor.capture(), String));

String argument = captor.getValue()
//suppose there is a list with valid Strings
validList.contains(argument);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will provide the expected behavior:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner;

import static org.mockito.Matchers.anyString;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class TestClass {

    @Mock
    private ServiceInvocation serviceInvocation;


    @Test
    public void testMethod() {
        when(serviceInvocation.isServiceNeeded(anyString(),anyString())).thenReturn(false);
        when(serviceInvocation.isServiceNeeded("1","AAS")).thenReturn(true);
        when(serviceInvocation.isServiceNeeded("2","AAS")).thenReturn(true);
        when(serviceInvocation.isServiceNeeded("3","AAS")).thenReturn(true);
        when(serviceInvocation.isServiceNeeded("4","AAS")).thenReturn(true);
        when(serviceInvocation.isServiceNeeded("5","AAS")).thenReturn(true);

        System.out.println(serviceInvocation.isServiceNeeded("1","AAS"));
        System.out.println(serviceInvocation.isServiceNeeded("2","AAS"));
        System.out.println(serviceInvocation.isServiceNeeded("3","AAS"));
        System.out.println(serviceInvocation.isServiceNeeded("4","AAS"));
        System.out.println(serviceInvocation.isServiceNeeded("5","AAS"));
        System.out.println(serviceInvocation.isServiceNeeded("other1","AAS"));
        System.out.println(serviceInvocation.isServiceNeeded("other2","AAS"));
        System.out.println(serviceInvocation.isServiceNeeded("3","AAS"));
    }
}
```

Result:

```
true
true
true
true
true
false
false
```

Answer (score 0):

I would solve the problem with ArgumentMatcher, like this:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.mockito.ArgumentMatcher;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import static org.mockito.Mockito.argThat;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

/**
 * <dependency>
 * <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
 * <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
 * <version>2.8.9</version>
 * <scope>test</scope>
 * </dependency>
 */
public class MockitoExample1 {


    @Test
    public void test1() {


        MyClass test = mock(MyClass.class);


        String sampleText = argThat(new MyMatcher());

        when(test.isServiceNeeded(sampleText)).thenReturn(true);

        boolean reply;
        reply = test.isServiceNeeded("0000000005");
        System.out.println(reply);  // true

        reply = test.isServiceNeeded("000000000x");
        System.out.println(reply);  // false

    }


}

class MyMatcher extends ArgumentMatcher<String> {

    @Override
    public boolean matches(Object argument) {
        List<String> validStrings = Arrays.asList("0000000001", "0000000002", "0000000003", "0000000004", "0000000005");
        if (validStrings.contains((String) argument)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}

class MyClass {
    public boolean isServiceNeeded(String text) {
        return true;
    }

}
```