# How to negate an ArgumentMatcher in Mockito?

Tags: mocking, mockito

I have created a `ArgumentMatcher`,

```
private class IsListOf2Elements implements ArgumentMatcher<List<String>>{
    @Override
    public boolean matches(List<String> argument) {
        return ((List<String>)argument).size()==2;
    }
}
```

I want to negate this match, so match when size is not 2,

```
Mockito.doReturn(false).when(mock).addAll(Mockito.argThat(AdditionalMatchers.not(new IsListOf2Elements())));
```

But this is not correct. I get,

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
No matchers found for additional matcher Not(?)
-> at my.test.own.Mockito_aTest.test4e(Mockito_aTest.java:136)
```

Answer (score 6):

For reference, be aware that [Hamcrest matchers and Mockito matchers behave very differently](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22822512/1426891). Hamcrest's stateless Matcher objects represent the match function as an instance, and can be wrapped to invert their results; Mockito's "registered matchers" work only via side-effects.

`argThat` adapts a Hamcrest matcher into a Mockito matcher, Hamcrest's `CoreMatchers.not` inverts a Hamcrest matcher, and Mockito's `AdditionalMatchers.not` inverts a Mockito matcher (via side-effects). This is part of the reason that `CoreMatchers.not` always returns a `Matcher<T>`, while `AddionalMatchers.not` returns an arbitrary `T`; it's operating on Mockito state you can't see.

This gives you the following behavior:

```
// BAD: Don't use AdditionalMatchers to invert a Hamcrest matcher.
doReturn(false).when(mock).addAll(
    Mockito.argThat(AdditionalMatchers.not(new IsListOf2Elements())));

// GOOD: Use AdditionalMatchers to invert a Mockito matcher. (See ericj's answer.)
doReturn(false).when(mock).addAll(
    AdditionalMatchers​.not(Mockito.argThat‌​(new IsListOf2Elements())));

// ALSO GOOD: Use CoreMatchers to invert a Hamcrest matcher. (See troig's answer.)
doReturn(false).when(mock).addAll(
    Mockito.argThat‌​(CoreMatchers.not(new IsListOf2Elements())));
```

If the exception you're making is about stubbed behavior, you can also use a [more-specific override](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34172381/1426891) to stub the general behavior in addition to the specific exception.

Comment: Great clarification!

Comment: @troig Thanks! Sorry to have forgotten to add a callout to your answer (and ericj's); just edited it in.

Comment: No worries at all :) I think @ericj should accept this answer.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be that you cannot use a custom matcher as `AdditionalMatchers.not` method parameter.

However, you can use hamcrest [org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers](http://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/hamcrest/CoreMatchers.html) instead. This should work:

```
Mockito.doReturn(false).when(mock).addAll(Mockito.argThat(CoreMatchers.not(new IsListOf2Elements())));
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Strange, It worked well for me. Maybe a versions issue, because ArgumentMatcher in my Mockito version (1.9.5) is an abstract class, not an interface like in your OP. Which versions are you using?

Comment: I resolved it. You have to switch: `Mockito.doReturn(false).when(mock).addAll(AdditionalMatchers.not(Mockito.argThat(new IsListOf2Elements())));`

Comment: Great! and thanks for letting me know. You should add your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer myself. Turn is around,

```
Mockito.doReturn(false).when(mock).addAll(AdditionalMatchers‌​.not(Mockito.argThat‌​(new IsListOf2Elements())));
```

The reason is that `AdditionalMatchers‌​.not` expects a registered matcher, and `Mockito.argThat‌` does do that.

Answer (score 0):

Just make this:

```
AdditionalMatchers.not(ArgumentMatchers.eq(...)
```