# Java mockito service test parameter negation

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, java-8, mockito

I try to test my service with mockito 2.7.15.

First I try this:

```
when(customerDaoMock.find(AdditionalMatchers.not(id1))).thenReturn(null);
```

But I got a `InvalidUseOfmatchersException`.. So I googled the problem and found this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40272700/7445344).
After that my second try would have been:

```
when(customerDaoMock.find(AdditionalMatchers.not(Mockito.argThat‌(id1)))).thenReturn(null);
```

but `Mockito` class has no longer method `argThat`

So my question is how can I use `not` negation method in mockito?

Or is there any other option, or better solution for this problem?

Comment: what's the "find" method signature?

Comment: from interface : public `Customer find(Long id);`

Comment: Do you need this statement `thenReturn(null)`? Any call to the mock without conditions returns null

Comment: Thx for the suggestion! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example from the AdditionalMatchers [javadoc](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.7.19/org/mockito/AdditionalMatchers.html):

```
//anything but not "ejb"
mock.someMethod(not(eq("ejb")));
```

Here is working example:

```
public static class Tmp {
    public String f(Long a) {
        return a.toString();
    }
}

@Test
public void mockitoTest() {
    Tmp mock = Mockito.mock(Tmp.class);
    when(mock.f(AdditionalMatchers.not(Mockito.eq(5L)))).thenReturn("42");

    Assert.assertEquals("42", mock.f(4L));
    Assert.assertNull(mock.f(5L));
}
```

Comment: Thx for the response! Unfortunataly AdditionalMatchers of mockito has no `eq` method with one parameter. (for Long)
Check this: "`The method eq(double, double) in the type AdditionalMatchers is not applicable for the arguments (Long)`"

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is more understandable without the static imports:

```
Mockito.when(customerDaoMock.find(AdditionalMatchers.not(Mockito.eq(id1))))
    .thenReturn(null);
```

So you can use [`ArgumentMatchers#eq(long)`](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.7.19/org/mockito/ArgumentMatchers.html#eq%28long%29) paired with [`AdditionalMatchers#not(long)`](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/1.9.5/org/mockito/AdditionalMatchers.html#not%28long%29).