# How do I test for inequality with Spring's MockMvc and jsonpath?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jsonpath

I am trying to test that a field in the response is **not** equal to some value, like such:

```
@Test
void whenAnAuth0ExceptionIsThrown_itShouldNotLeakInformation() throws Exception {
    String description = "Resource not found.";
    Auth0Exception auth0Exception = new Auth0Exception(description);

    when(usersService.getRoles()).thenThrow(new UnrecoverableAuthException("api exception", auth0Exception));

    mockMvc.perform(get("/v1/users/roles").with(csrf()))
        .andExpect(status().isInternalServerError())
        .andExpect(jsonPath("$.errorMessage").value(AdditionalMatchers.not(description)));


    verify(usersService).getRoles();
}
```

But when I try this, I get the following error:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
No matchers found for additional matcher Not(?)
```

A workaround that I've found is to use `andReturn()` and then test the `MvcResult`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to negate an ArgumentMatcher in Mockito?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40215935/how-to-negate-an-argumentmatcher-in-mockito)

Comment: @AkshayG Using `Mockito.argThat` results in a compilation error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close.

```
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.not;
... 
.andExpect(jsonPath("$.errorMessage").value(not(description)));
```

Comment: Thank you. For some reason intellij was not recommending hamcrest at all, even though it is on my classpath via spring boot.