# Is there a `not` ArgumentMatcher for mockito stubbing

Tags: java, mockito, hamcrest

I am trying to verify that a method is called with a `long` having any value but a given one.

I thus would like to know if there is an `ArgumentMatcher` that fits to my use case, such as:

```java
verify(mObject).verifiedMethod(notEq(longValueThatShouldBeAvoided));
```

---

I found this workaround:

```java
verify(mObject).method(longThat(arg -> arg != longValueThatShouldBeAvoided));
```

But I find weird that such simple `ArgumentMatcher` has to be written from scratch.

---

Additional question: 
How to proceed when checking for multiple values to avoid ?

Similarly, I found the workaround of using `arg -> arg != val0 && arg != val1` lambda as parameter of [`ArgumentsMatcher.longThat`](https://www.javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.2.4/org/mockito/ArgumentMatchers.html#longThat-org.mockito.ArgumentMatcher-) method to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
import static org.mockito.AdditionalMatchers.not; 
import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.eq;

verify(mObject).verifiedMethod(not(eq(longValueThatShouldBeAvoided)));
```

Comment: Would you mind to specify which `not` method you suggest please ? I mean, which package it is declared in.

Comment: @EnzoMolion 
`import static org.mockito.AdditionalMatchers.not;
import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.eq;`

Comment: It worked, thanks ! I thought I tried this but my IDE was actually importing `org.hamcrest.Matcher`'s `not`...

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be looking for the "not" matcher in [AdditionalMatchers](https://javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.2.4/org/mockito/AdditionalMatchers.html).

However, I think that is dealt with more extensively in [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34171082/how-to-handle-any-other-value-with-mockito).

Comment: While this question actually perfectly answers my question and several others do, I did not find them during my research, sorry about that.