# Mockito ArgumentMatchers doesNotMatch?

Tags: java, regex, mockito, matcher

`ArgumentMatchers.matches( String regex )` exists... and it is possible to devise regexes which **don't** match a given `String`.  But it is far from trivial (several threads in SO).

Is it wrong of me (or wrong-headed) to think it might be a nice idea to request the Mockito designers to take the heavy-lifting out of this and add it as a feature? It just seems that, in the context of mocking and so forth, it is a far-from-exceptional use case...

PS also, I'm not clear with `ArgumentMatchers.matches` how you go about saying "this may be a multiline String we're matching against, don't worry about it"... wouldn't it be better to have a `Pattern` rather than a simple `String`?

***later***

[Feature request](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues/838) "enhanced" at Mockito HQ (on Github). "bric3" there says one should use Jeff Bowman's technique for "does not match".  But she/he seems to think the `Pattern` idea is worth thinking about.

Re `not()`: Mockito's [own documentation](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.1.0-RC.1/org/mockito/AdditionalMatchers.html) says "Use additional matchers very judiciously because they may impact readability of a test. It is recommended to use matchers from Matchers and keep stubbing and verification simple."

Also I find I must "possible dupe" my own question: [How to write a matcher that is not equal to something](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26067096/how-to-write-a-matcher-that-is-not-equal-to-something). Searching with hindsight is always easier...!

***later still***

Many thanks to Brice for adding this so quickly. Updated my gradle.build and... new 4.1 core downloaded from Maven Central and immediately available for use.

Comment: This would be an excellent post for the Mockito mailing list.  And you can always make a feature request to the Mockito team.  Feature requests usually spark some debate within the team about whether or not the feature is a good idea - sometimes requested features get developed quickly, sometimes they take a while but get developed eventually, and sometimes they get rejected.  But there's never any harm in making a request.

Comment: Thanks for the encouragement. Jeff Bowman's response goes in a totally different direction.  AdditionalMatchers.not.  I think it would propably have taken me about 13 years to have stumbled on that. There's probably only a small bunch of potential purchasers, but have any of you experts ever thought of writing a book entitled "Intermediate Mockito" or "Mockito: taking it to another level"?

Comment: Actually, I started work on a fairly comprehensive book on Mockito a few years ago.  The problem is that Mockito is growing and changing faster than I can write, with new features being added all the time.  By the time I get to publish, the information in my book would be out of date.  So I have abandoned the project.  What I really need to do is to start a blog and turn my material into a series of posts - maybe another day I'll do that.

Comment: Google Tomek Kaczanowski - he's written some good books on Mockito.

Comment: Of course.  When I say "book" I don't envisage bits of paper. Might it be reasonable to suppose the pace of change is likely to slacken sooner or later? One of the things I have read over recent months while trying to teach myself mocking suggested that PowerMock, for example, possibly involves "too much magic".  There's probably a natural plateau which Mockito will reach ... so it wouldn't be wasted effort on your part (necessarily!).

Comment: "Tomek Kaczanowski" - yep, one of the books I've spent many hours concentrating on.  But it's not intermediate.  There is no intermediate tutorial anywhere (that I'm aware of).

Comment: I'm not sure whether "not intermediate" means it's too basic or too advanced.

Comment: Yes, too basic (after a lot of head-scratching and experimenting... )... but I'm being told to stop!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No need for a request: You can compose what you want using [AdditionalMatchers.not](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.3.10/org/mockito/AdditionalMatchers.html#not(T)).

```
when(yourComponent.acceptString(not(matches("foo|ba[rz]"))))
    .thenThrow(new IllegalArgumentException());
```

If you want to match a Pattern, you might need to write your own [ArgumentMatcher](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.3.10/org/mockito/ArgumentMatcher.html) subclass, but it's quite easy from there:

```
public class MatchesPattern implements ArgumentMatcher<String> {
  private final Pattern pattern;
  public MatchesPattern(Pattern pattern) { this.pattern = pattern; }

  @Override public boolean matches(String string) {
    return pattern.matcher(string).matches();
  }

  @Override public String toString() {
    return "[string matching /" + pattern.toString() + "/]";
  }

  /** Optional. */
  public static MatchesPattern matchesPattern(Pattern pattern) {
    return new MatchesPattern(pattern);
  }
}
```

You can then consume that class using:

```
when(yourComponent.acceptString(not(argThat(new MatchesPattern(yourPattern)))
    .thenThrow(new IllegalArgumentException());

// or with the static factory method:
when(yourComponent.acceptString(not(argThat(matchesPattern(yourPattern)))
    .thenThrow(new IllegalArgumentException());
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks, Jeff, you are the go-to man for all things Mockito!

Answer (score 4):

For future readers, [Mockito 2.4.1](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/blob/release/2.x/doc/release-notes/official.md#241-2016-12-22-1402-utc) has been released with support of the `Pattern` class :

Now you should be abble to write :

```
when(yourComponent.acceptString(not(matches(Pattern.compile(...)))
    .thenThrow(new IllegalArgumentException());
```

Comment: Impressive timing on that one!

Comment: I was available. Also thanks to our automated release process.