# Mockito modify method behavior

Tags: java, mockito

I have the following interface:

```
public interface Test{
    public void block(String modifier);
    public boolean blocked(String modifier);
}
```

So I wanted to mock this interface as follows:

```
Test m = Mockito.mock(Test.class);
when(m.blocked(Mockito.any()).thenReturn(true);
//I want to mock m.block()
```

Buty I want to mock `Test::block(String)` the way so when it is called on some `String someString` it changes the behavior so that `m.blocked(someString)` will return `false`.

Is it possible to do so in Mockito?

Comment: You could have a boolean field, and rather then use thenReturn, use thenAnswer and create a logic using this field

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26067096/how-to-write-a-matcher-that-is-not-equal-to-something

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `thenAnswer` and `doAnswer` to execute arbitrary code when a method is called. For example, you could use a `Set` to keep track of the strings that have already been blocked:

```
Set<Object> blocked = new HashSet<>();
Test m = mock(Test.class);
doAnswer(invocation -> blocked.add(invocation.getArguments()[0]))
    .when(m).block(any());
when(m.blocked(any()))
    .thenAnswer(invocation -> !blocked.contains(invocation.getArguments()[0]));
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a sample, assuming you have a boolean field that starts as true --

```
when(m.blocked(Mockito.any()).thenAnswer(invocation -> this.mockValue);
when(m.block(Mockito.eq("Some String")).thenAnswer(invocation -> {
    this.mockValue = false;
    return null;
});
```

Hopefully I didn't get the syntax wrong :-)